# android + gmail + feed + get ALL mails

Tags: android, gmail

If I use https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ feed from gmail, I get ONLY unread emails - as a nice XML parseable by any reader.

Please tell me if there is a way to get ALL emails - including both read and unread?
I am trying this on Android. Is there any example I could refer to?

Thanks,
A

Comment: See existing question. Read https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179103/read-all-mails-from-gmail-api-using-oauth

Comment: can you post your code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite limiting, because [`http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/inbox/`](http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/inbox/) AND [`https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/`](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/) shows all unread mail, not simply the inbox, as it should in my opintion. Then we could have `/read` and `/unread` but instead `/read` doesn't exist and `/unread` gives you all unread, not simply the unread from the inbox.

So, [`http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/all`](http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/all) may be what you want as it gives you literally ALL mail. At the moment, using an atom feed alone like that, you would only be able to get ALL mail, like you asked for, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking for...I'd assume you want ALL (meaning read/unread) from the INBOX. At the moment, that's not possible, using the feed, and you are stuck with all mail from all labels where they necessarily and likely don't all live in the inbox (many have items skip the inbox purposefully).

References:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/feed-for-unread-gmail-messages.html

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed